# How to open excel file in Polars dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, python-polars

I am a python pandas user but recently found about polars dataframe and it seems quite promising and blazingly fast. I am not able to find a way to open an excel file in polars. Polars is happily reading `csv`, `json`, etc. but not excel.

I am extensive user of excel files in pandas and I want to try using polars. I have many sheets in excel that pandas automatically read. How can I do same with polars?

What am I missing?

Comment: have a look at the library's [API](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/) and see if it offers a way to read excel files

Comment: Sorry but it looks like Polars does not have any read/write functions for the excel format. If you can, I would recommend start saving data in csv format or sql.

Comment: Yes it seems so that there is currently no option in polars to read/write excel. I am receiving my data daily in excel format in multiple sheets, converting it to csv will again consume more time. Instead i will continue with pandas till there is some solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than a real answer, but you can read it into pandas and then convert it to a polars dataframe.

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(...)
df_pl = pl.DataFrame(df)
```

You could, however, make a feature request to the Apache Arrow community to support excel files.

Answer (score 6):

Polars now has a `read_excel` method, as of this [PR](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/3567)!

https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_excel.html

You should be able to just do:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.read_excel("file.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues to open excel file with `pl.read_excel` and there is a config that works for me:

```py
import polars as pl
df_pl = pl.read_excel("YOUR_FILE_DIR", read_csv_options={"infer_schema_length": 10000})
df_pl.head()
```

> Notice: This option is only applicable when using the xlsx2csv engine.

[Doc](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_excel.html)

Answer (score 0):

pl.read_excel frequently make memory short error,
pd.read_excel do well.  so, I use this way.

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(...)
df_pl = pl.DataFrame(df)
```